# Using awk to filter out a term and keep the remainder

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` on my `test.csv` file to filter out rows containing a set of terms to produce two files: `terms.csv` and `notterms.csv`.

I am trying to repurpose this code designed to remove duplicates (which works well):

`awk -F "," 'seen[$2]++{print $0 > "Duplicates.csv"; next}{print $0 > "UniqueTitles.csv"}' test.csv`

into this which doesn't work:

`awk -F "," '$2==Bobby && $2==Cathy++{print $0 > "Duplicates.csv"; next}{print $0 > "UniqueTitles.csv"}' test.csv`

My test.csv is:

```
Book,Author,Age,Sex,Parent
Apples in May, Bobby, 12, M, Yes
Apples in June, Prisca, 16, F, Yes
Notes in sleep, Bobby, 12, M, Yes
Plastic Recycling, Cathy, 16, F, No
```

I want it to produce one file named `terms.csv` with:

```
Book,Author,Age,Sex,Parent
Apples in May, Bobby, 12, M, Yes
Notes in sleep, Bobby, 12, M, Yes
Plastic Recycling, Cathy, 16, F, No
```

and another named `notterms.csv` with:

```
Book,Author,Age,Sex,Parent
Apples in June, Prisca, 16, F, Yes
```

However, I keep getting an error saying there is a syntax error at the `++{` location. How do I solve this. I am not very good with awk.

I am currently using GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1) on MXLinux, Kernel: 5.16.0-5mx-amd64

Comment: as coded `Bobby` and `Cathy` are variables; I'm guessing what  you meant was to test for the values in the fields in which case you need to wrap in double quotes (to signify they are strings); how can `$2` be both `"Bobby"` and `"Cathy"` at the same time? why is the `Prisca` record showing in both files? what happend to the 2nd `Bobby` record?

Comment: You are right. I have made the correction. Thank you.

Comment: so you want *ALL* `Bobby` and `Cathy` records in the `terms.csv` file and everything else in the `notterms.csv` file?

Comment: Yes. ALL `Bobby` and `Cathy` terms in `terms.csv` file and everything else in the `notterms.csv` @markp-fuso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is intended by `$2==Cathy++` but from the expected contents of the `terms.csv` and `notterms.csv` files it looks like all records with the 2nd field = `Bobby` or `Cathy` should go in `terms.csv` while all other records go into `notterms.csv`.

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -F "," '
FNR==1 { print $0 > "terms.csv"                           # write header row 
         print $0 > "notterms.csv"                        # to both files
         next
       }
       { name=$2
         sub(/^[ ]+|[ ]+$/,"",name)                       # strip leading/trailing spaces from name
         if (name == "Bobby" || name == "Cathy")
            print $0 > "terms.csv"
         else
            print $0 > "notterms.csv"
       }
' test.csv
```

This generates:

```
$ head *terms.csv
==> notterms.csv <==
Book,Author,Age,Sex,Parent
Apples in June, Prisca, 16, F, Yes

==> terms.csv <==
Book,Author,Age,Sex,Parent
Apples in May, Bobby, 12, M, Yes
Notes in sleep, Bobby, 12, M, Yes
Plastic Recycling, Cathy, 16, F, No
```